# JSON Thumbnail image in Custom Table View Cell

Tags: ios, json, image, parsing

I really get tired of trying to fix this so I think I need some help. I am filling each Cells of my iOS from an API which I successfully parsed (Can retrieve simple things such as texts, or numbers with no problem)
But when I tried to set the images for the thumbnails I am having some errors.

This is my code:

```
NSString *imageUrl = [tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"files.url_thumb"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *thumbNailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    [cell.ThumbImage setImage:thumbNailImage];
});
```

and this are the nightmares in my console:

```
2015-04-08 13:14:26.450 WebTableView[4976:173380] -[__NSArrayI length]: 

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e18b90
2015-04-08 13:14:26.509 WebTableView[4976:173380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e18b90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x036c9466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03352a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x036d12c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x03619bc7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0361978e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x035836cf CFStringGetLength + 143
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x036a9c8d _CFURLCreateWithURLString + 77
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x035952d3 CFURLCreateWithString + 35
    8   Foundation                          0x02f17999 -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithString:relativeToURL:] + 371
    9   Foundation                          0x02f17807 +[NSURL(NSURL) URLWithString:relativeToURL:] + 80
    10  Foundation                          0x02f177b1 +[NSURL(NSURL) URLWithString:] + 48
    11  WebTableView                        0x00111a8b -[TableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 571
    12  UIKit                               0x01c26c9c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 473
    13  UIKit                               0x01c26d7e -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 77
    14  UIKit                               0x01c0054b -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3034
    15  UIKit                               0x01c1aeb1 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    16  UIKit                               0x01b907b1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
    17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03368771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    18  QuartzCore                          0x009421cf -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00936055 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00935eb0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    21  QuartzCore                          0x008941b6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0089558a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00895c56 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x035ec18e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x035ec0d0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x035e1b0a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x035e137b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x035e11ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x04b3d2c1 GSEventRunModal + 192
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x04b3d0fe GSEventRun + 104
    31  UIKit                               0x01b049b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    32  WebTableView                        0x000dd6cd main + 141
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x03e94ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I would love some help here

Comment: cell.ThumbImage is UIImageView? try this - [cell.ThumbImage.image setImage:thumbNailImage];

Comment: thanks for your response @UttamSinha, I tried that... but gives me failed. "no visible interface for 'UImage' declares the selector of 'setImage:'"

Comment: what is imageUrl you are getting?

Comment: @UttamSinha I am trying to get "url_thumb" which is an image and it's inside of "files" `"expenses_price" = 0;
        files =         (
                        {
                "date_modified" = "<null>";
                entity = ad;
                "entity_id" = 1;
                file = 1;
                id = 1;
                target = main;
                type = 1;
                "url_thumb" = "http://dev.geoplem.com/images/pub/tn/538928ed35fde138844865.jpg";
            }
        );
        latitude = "-34.57496820";`

Comment: Can you share cellForRowAtIndexPath & numberofRows code?

Comment: Of course: http://pastie.org/10089830 thank you @UttamSinha

Comment: i think issue in this line - NSString *titulo = [tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"title"]; why are you using valueForKeyPath? it should be valueForKey.

Answer (score 0):

I think valueForKeyPath: returning an array of objects. Try logging imageUrl and check what you are getting.

If you are confident that there would be only one url then you can try this -

```
NSString *imageUrl = [[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"files.url_thumb"] lastObject];
```

Else try something like this -

```
valueForKey:@"files"] valueForKey:@"url_thumb]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went for the 2nd option since I am using a lists of urls images. And I get the same error: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` this is more complicated than I have ever expected.

Comment: Did you log imageUrl? NSLog("%@", imageUrl); check are you getting url here or app terminating at this point. Use breakpoint to check the flow where its crashing.

Comment: It crashes here: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]; "Signal SIGABRT thread:1"

Comment: Crash report says same? Earlier it was due to [__NSArrayI length], what is the console log now? Also, i just hit the image url in the browser it asks for authentication username & password.

Comment: This is the console log right now: http://pastie.org/10088792 it's protected with username & password which already have and perfectly works, I get the text from the json fine. Now, the images are giving me headaches. I would like to note that some tries before I could get one simple image in each cell (repeated), but since isn't what I want to do I edited the code to have each corresponding image in each cell. thank you again